# Are 'The Forty Rules of Love' real?

Tags: the-forty-rules-of-love, elif-shafak

One of the best-selling 21st-century novels, *[The Forty Rules of Love](https://www.goodreads.com/author_blog_posts/5965469-the-story-behind-the-forty-rules-of-love)*, shows historical fiction employing the love of *Shams of Tabraiz* and *Mevlana Rumi*. Were those 40 rules by Shams or were they made by Elif too?